# Multistore issue Duplicate content issue

Tags: multistore, seo, page-content

We have multiple Store 3 Stores we are using same products in all..

Can someone give me idea how we can prevent for duplicate?

we are using some product on our client site. with shop.domain.com we want this all product or pages should not be index by google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `robots` tag for this. 
Putting it on `noindex` will prevent Google from indexing it.

You can either set it site wide via `System > Configuration > Design > Head` or per product under editing a product, tab design and add the following to custom layout

```
<STORE_[code]>
      <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</meta></action>
      </reference>
 </STORE_[code]>
```

Comment: ok home page we can do this with this tag. fine but what about products. we are using same products on all website. if we block it. its will be no index from all sites

Comment: @Rajnesh updated! Or switch store views in the left top of the admin view

Comment: thanks its can be a solution. 
<reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</meta></action>
      </reference>

its working fine. plus with bulk attribute update we can do this in bulk too thanks a lots.

Comment: @SanderMangel Can i get help regard the same issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/324379/57334 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether it works but it does hide the products from the categories.

Using this code also hides the products from front end display:

> `<reference name="head"> <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</meta></action> </reference>`