# Magento 2.3 - How to handle multi store same product name duplicates error when edit?

Tags: magento2.3.4, duplicate

I have migrated Magento from 1.9.2.3 to 2.3.4, if i try to change the product details i am getting error like **product name isn't unique**. I am using multi-Store so that the same product name available in all stores How to handle this issue? I can't able to import the product images.

Anybody faced this, How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If all the products name the same in different stores then I would suggest deleting those products' names from the table(catalog_product_entity_varchar).

Forex: Keep all the value assigned to store (0) and remove other store values from the table.

Don't forget to take a backup before doing the above changes in the database.

Hope this will help you.